# Is there a way to programmatically attach to process with python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to add function in my python code so that whenever I call it, it will auto attach to the process that runs it using the debugger of pycharm.

for example:

```
# some code 
# some code
# attach_here(pid)
# some code
# some code
```

is there way to do that?

Comment: You can add pre-run scripts to your normal attach configurations, iirc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the ability to attach to local processes, but this is effectively how the `remote debugger` works. Setup PyCharm for remote debug usage, and then in your code when `pydevd.settrace(...)` is called, it connects to the debugger.